# ssh to my compute engine machine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Two days ago I've created a compute engine instance and connected to it with ssh, everything was fine, after testing different things i've deleted the machine and disk.
Today I've created a new instance in compute engine, getinstance as well as the console show the instance running.

But when trying to connect to the instance I'm getting a messegebox asking for: enter your password for the ssh key "google compute engine"

the password i'm entering is getting denied

how can I change the password for this project? this user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how I resolved the issue:

1. turn hidden files on on finder (by running: defaults write
   com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE)
2. going to $HOME/.ssh directory and delete the files google_compute_engine, google_compute_engine.pub
3. call gcutil ssh again which created new files with new passphrase
4. when prompted again enter the passphrase and connection established :)

Comment: You are making a living here in SO on answering your own questions then answering them eh? I looked at the first 5 you had answered and all five were originally asked by you.

Comment: @bma I ask a question that I don't know the answer to as I'm coding my project, if while trying I found a solution and no one had given an answer yet, I add the solution so others as well as myself will know what to do next time. sorry if it bothers you, hope my answer helped you!

Comment: I had the same problem. After deleting both files, I executed gcloud compute config-ssh in the cloud console to generate new keys. Worked like a charm.